# why redirection &>file with readline in a pipe breaks, but not 1>file or 2>file

Tags: c, shell, pipe, readline

readline might not be the problem, but i can't reproduce this behavior without it

here is a minimalist reproduction of a shell, it prints a prompt on STDOUT and if the command start with "echo " it prints what comes next :

*mybash.c* :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int     main(void)
{
    char    *prompt;
    char    *line_input;

    prompt = "[mybash]> ";
    while (1)
    {
        line_input = readline(prompt);
        if (line_input)
        {
            if (!strncmp(line_input, "echo ", 5))
            {
                write(1, line_input + 5, strlen(line_input) - 5);
                write(1, "\n", 1);
            }
            free(line_input);
        }
        if (!line_input)
        {
            write(2, "exit\n", 5);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

at first it looks like it works fine :

*exit happens because i press Ctrl-D, or in later examples because pipes ends*

```
[bash]$ gcc mybash.c -lreadline
[bash]$ ./a.out
[mybash]> echo hello
hello
[mybash]> anything
[mybash]> exit
[bash]$
```

now i put it in a pipe to capture the output

```
[bash]$ echo "echo hello" | ./a.out &>file.log
[bash]$ cat file.log
 [mybash]> echo hello
 hello
 [mybash]> exit
[bash]$
```

*(i added the empty space at beginning of lines in cat output for readability)*

ok, now i change the prompt for something very long :

```
prompt = WHITE"[mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> "RESET;
```

and the output works fine in classic interactivity, it works also fine in pipes with a redirection of only STDERR or STDOUT, but if i redirect both, it breaks :

*interactive prompt :*

```
[bash]$ ./a.out
[mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> echo hello
hello
[mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> anything
[mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> exit
[bash]$
```

*pipe without redirection :*

```
[bash]$ echo "echo hello" | ./a.out
[mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> echo hello
hello
[mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> anything
[mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> exit
[bash]$
```

*in case it's not clear, i only wrote the first command `echo "echo hello" | ./a.out`, the rest prompted "automatically", unlike the previous example*

*STDOUT redirection :*

```
[bash]$ echo "echo hello" | ./a.out 1>file.log
exit
[bash]$ cat file.log
 [mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> echo hello
 hello
 [mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> [%]
[bash]$
```

*STDERR redirection :*

```
[bash]$ echo "echo hello" | ./a.out 2>file.log
[mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> echo hello
hello
[mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> [%]
[bash]$ cat file.log
 exit
[bash]$
```

*STDOUT and STDERR redirections in interactive mode :*

```
[bash]$ ./a.out &>file.log
(i type here without seeing anything)
[bash]$ cat file.log
 [mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> echo hello
 hello
 [mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> anything
 [mybash_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]> exit
[bash]$
```

*and STDOUT & STDERR redirections in pipe :*

```
[bash]$ echo "echo hello" | ./a.out &>file.log
[bash]$ cat file.log
 _file]>echo hellog_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a
 hello
  exith_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]>
[bash]$
```

*sorry, colors of stackoverflow breaks a little in this example*

as you can see, in the last example the prompt line doesn't go to a new line, it writes over itself at the beginning, but it only occurs with `&>` redirection and pipes, i don't understand why ?

and of course, the same tests on `bash` instead of `mybash` works very well, the prompt doesn't break

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug. I can reproduce it with libreadline v7 but not with v8. With v7 I get:

```
cat file.log
]> echo helloy_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]
hello
]> exit_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]
```

You can run the commands through `strace`:

```bash
... strace -x -f -o strace1.out -s 2048 ./a.out ...
```

and compare. You will notice that if at least one input or output is real terminal, you get:

```
ioctl(2, TCGETS, ... = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, ... = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

or

```
ioctl(2, TCGETS, ... = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(0, TCGETS, ... = 0
```

and then:

```
write(1, "[..._in_a_file]> ", 83) = 83
```

But when none of the inputs nor outputs are real terminal, e.g. input is a pipe and output is redirection to a file, you get:

```
ioctl(2, TCGETS, ... = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
ioctl(0, TCGETS, ... = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
...
write(1, "[..._in_a_file]\r]> ", 85) = 85
```

Notice that `\r]>`? The `\r` causes overwriting.

EDIT

Some more info. The readline library tries to detect the width of the screen in [`_rl_get_screen_size()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/terminal.c?h=readline-7.0#n225). There are 3 possibilities here (at least on my machine):

- `stdin` is connected to TTY (i.e. it is not from pipe or redirected from file) – then `ioctl(TIOCGWINSZ)` kicks in and returns correct value, 180
- otherwise `tgetnum ("co")` kicks in and:

  - returns correct value if at least one of `stdout` or `stderr` is connected to TTY,
  - or returns 80 if both are redirected to a file.

The library has very complex display function [`rl_redisplay()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-7.0#n578). It spans almost 800 lines. One of the things it does is handling a wrap-around, for example when the prompt is longer than the screen width. It calls [`update_line()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-7.0#n1368) (another 600 lines), which calls [`_rl_move_cursor_relative()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-7.0#n2151), which [puts CR character](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/display.c?h=readline-7.0#n2254) if conditions are right. And the conditions are right when all streams are redirected and the screen width is detected to be 80.

From reading `_rl_get_screen_size()`, there is also a way to force those conditions when only `stdin` is redirected, by using `COLUMNS` environment variable:

```
]$ echo "echo hello" | COLUMNS=80 ./a.out
]> echo helloy_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]
hello
]> exit_a_very_long_prompt_to_test_the_output_in_case_of_a_redirection_in_a_file]
```

Comment: ok, that's interesting :) i didn't know strace, i'll try it, and change for libreadline v8 then :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong, AFAIK.

Use `echo "echo hello" | ./a.out 1>file.log 2>&1`.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: i think the syntax is not wrong : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html section "3.6.4 Redirecting Standard Output and Standard Error", plus i did some tests and it works. Although your syntax works as well

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll delete my answer soon, as it would lead to wrong conclusions.